# How did Anne Conway derive her notion of a monad from the Kabbalah?

Tags: leibniz

Lady Conway was a 17th century Philosopher. The SEP entry on [her](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/conway/) states:

> Her concept of the monad, which is indebted to the Kabbalism, anticipates Leibniz.

I have only the slightest acquaintance with Jewish [Kabbalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabbalah) - and generally think of it as a part of Jewish mysticism or esoterism. How did the Kabbalah inspire her notion of a monad?

Comment: @allegranza: if you put this into an answer I can accept this; its likely to be the best answer to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to follow the traces ...

Anne Conway => [Cambridge Platonists](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/cambridge-platonists/) => [Henry More](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/henry-more/) => Renaissance Neoplatonism : mainly [Marsilio Ficino](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ficino/) and [Giovanni Pico della Mirandola](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pico-della-mirandola/) => rediscovery of "ancient wisdow" : Moises, [Hermes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermeticism), Cabala.

You can see at least the "classic" : See F.A.Yates, [Giordano Bruno and the Hermetic Tradition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226950077) (1964).